# Need to have list elements come in 1 by 1

Tags: jquery, animation

Using a php function to create list elements from an array, would like to have each list element however come in 1 by 1 with about a 1.5sec delay between each,
Can someone give me the simplest way of achieving this? I'm assuming jquery is involved.

This is the code that brings in the list items from the array:

```
<?php include("inc/thumbs.php") ?>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <?php foreach($thumbs as $thumb) { 
                        echo get_thumb_view_html($thumb);
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you assume correctly. PHP cannot do much to control if/when a browser will render a particular element in a document.

Comment: Something along the lines of `setInterval(function() { //append row }, 150);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use JS or jQuery. Here's a quick example of using jQuery to append a new `li` every 1.5 seconds from an array of content:

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
var arrayCounter = 0;

var timeout = setInterval(function() {
    if (arrayCounter < array.length) {
        $("#testUL").append("<li>" + array[arrayCounter] + "</li>");
        arrayCounter++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(timeout);
    }
}, 1500);
```

Demo Page: http://jsfiddle.net/TstTA/1/

Comment: Is there a way for me to add this jquery to my existing php approach without having to remove it?

Comment: Depends, is the list being loaded on page load or triggered on an event

Comment: It's being loaded on page load